# How can I find a replacement external tub drain if the original has no identifiable markings?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

We are rebuilding a bathroom in a house in Long Island, New York. We would like to replace this external tub drain with the same. It has no identifiable markings. We need the make or model, or even the proper description would help.

![image: external tub drain.]

[image]

Comment: That's a "Standing Waste": http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/46954/how-does-an-external-tower-style-bathtub-drain-work

Answer (score 1):

Are you reinstalling a clawfoot or similar tub? Is this the overflow?  Was the bottom of the tub drain connected where the plastic fitting is?

[Many vendors supply clawfoot tub reproduction plumbing](http://www.vintagetub.com/asp/product_detail.asp?item_no=p0342c).  The outlet sizes of the tub (both overflow and drain) determine the connections to be used.  The older clawfoots used 1 3/8 piping, the newer (and replacements, but check if its 100% reproduction) ones 1 1/2.

Comment: This is the overflow and the stopper.