# How to adjust tub water level with standing waste stopper?

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

I have an old tub with a standing waste stopper. When the drain is closed, if the water level gets too high, it automatically drains down to a fixed level. That level was 3/4 of the tub depth, until the building maintenance man did something to the standing waste mechanism--he doesn't know what--and it now drains to about a third of the tub depth. In order to take a bath, I have to use a rubber disk over the drain.  Very frustrating.

Anyone know what he might have done to make this happen? If so, what can I do to restore it to the previous level?  Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/46954/43874 - I assume this is also what this question is referring to.

Comment: Based on how the device works, for the tub to drain down to 1/3 full and stop, the inner stopper tube would have to be cracked or have a hole corroded in it (I think, never used one).  Looks like unscrewing the top and pulling out the tube for inspection would be easy enough.

Comment: Any chance of opening up the drain and posting pictures?

Comment: Thank you!! The link to which you refer does indeed show the type of drain I have -- that posting inspired me to ask my question here.  I pulled out the tube, and don't see a hole, crack or any corrosion. This may be noteworthy:   there is threading at the bottom interior of the inner tube. Nothing was attached to it, but it came right out -- is it supposed to be screwed into the pipe at the base, or should have a bottom piece of some sort? I can't tell much by looking into the outer tube with a light, and it's cemented into the floor.